# How to update a table from Ajax post callback Symfony 3

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, html-table

I have a table that needs to be updated by Ajax callback, I'm really struggling to find the right way to do so.

Here is a picture how the table should look like:

[image]

I cannot find the right way to so, here is my current HTML script:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>12NC</th>
    <th>Object Description</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><input id="ID"></th>
        <td><input id="NC"></td>
        <td><input id="Des"></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

And here is the callbacks from Ajax:

```
                        person_name:$('#input_text').val()
                     } ,
                     function (data)
                     {
                         obj1 = data[0];
                         obj2 = data[1];

                          var obj =  JSON.parse(obj2);
                          var obj1 =  JSON.parse(obj1);



                         $('#ID').val(obj1[1].id);
                         $('#NC').val(obj1[1].n_c);
                         $('#Des').val(obj[1].description);
                     }
                 );
             })
            }
        );
```

Can someone please tell me if I'm doing it right and how I can send all the values from because now I can send only value [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ALrJ.jpg) from the array.

Comment: is this the full ajax code?

Comment: NO, but I find that is not needed to put all the code, beceuse here I'm trying to send the data to the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a success function in ajax. easier option would be to echo the value from the php page where ajax response is sent. such as

```
echo '<tr>
        <td scope="row">' . $idValue . '</th>
        <td>' . $12ncValue . '</td>
        <td>' . $descriptionValue . '</td>
      </tr>';
```

and in the success function you can append to the tbody after you give it a class or id.

```
<tbody id="tbody">


success: function (response) {
                    $('#tbody').append(response);
                   }
```

as for another approach would be declare an array of variables, and

```
echo json_encode($array)
```

and with .each function  you can loop the data from the ajax success function.

Edit: if you get the value. you need to append them. give id to tbody

```
</tbody id="tbody">
```

and in function(data)

```
 $('#tbody').append('<tr><td>'+obj1[1].id+'</td><td>'+obj1[1].n_c+'</td><td>'+obj[1].description+'</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Mohamad thank you for your answer, but is there way I can send it directly to the a twig loop.

Comment: basically if i return and array of data to the Ajax post, then I can send the object to twig  {% for connector in  connectors %}
                    <tr id="{{ connector.id }}">
                        <td>{{ connector.nC }}</td>
                        <td>{{ connector.description }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}  Ho I can send it to the twig loop.

Comment: you can use twig loop on the echo if you decide not to use json. but twig loop being php as far as my knowledge goes. success function being javascript. you can do a twig loop. but you can do a javascript .foreach loop if you decide to go with json.

Comment: i don't follow what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my question Mohamed, my aim is to make a ajax post to an entity and the received data from the entity to update instantly the table, without refreshing the the page. I can receive the data from the entity to my callback data, but I don't know how to update the table, that is why i ask if htere is a way to directly send the value to the the twig.

Comment: i have updated my answer, check if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Mohamed, thank you for your answer, It works, One more think can you tell me how I can refresh the table, so if i have requested new values I want the old to be removed.. Thanks again

Comment: You can do $('#tbody').empty(). Append() where empty removes all child elements and contents of tbody before appending